# HTML Tidy - no warning if quotes are missing

Tags: html, xml, tidy, htmltidy

Is there any option I can setup to make tidy showing me warnings if quotes are missing around attribute values? At the moment I run tidy as follows:

```
tidy -xml -e test.html
```

Within `test.html`:

```
<p id=foobar></p>
```

There's no warning but actually XML requires quotes. I don't need the corrected output. I want to use the `-e` Option.

HTML Tidy for Windows released on 25 March 2009

Comment: Does it correctly insert quotes when producing output? Does it make a difference if you use a complete HTML document rather than just a one-line fragment?

Comment: In my one-off tests, it did properly quote the attribute values when producing output, regardless of whether or not the input was a document or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Tidy will not throw warnings about attributes missing quotes as attribute values without spaces are valid in HTML (although not in XML, as you point out).  I've checked the documentation [here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/Overview.html) and [here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html) and unfortunately, I don't see any references to configuration options or settings that would yield the results you want.